# Attributes missing when a product is loaded via grouped products

Tags: catalog, eav, debugging

I have some simple products which are associated to a grouped product.

If I load the simple product separately, the attribute `tax_class_id` is set, but if the product is contained in a grouped product (fetched in `\Example_CatalogGrouped_Model_Product_Type_Grouped::getAssociatedProducts`), the `tax_class_id` is empty.

In the backend, the value is present.

Logging the SQL queries revealed, that the data is loaded from the EAV.

The query contains the following part (attribute id of `tax_class_id` is 85), but the value is not present in the result:

Checking the query which loaded the products, there is a the condition

```
UNION ALL SELECT
            `t_d`.`entity_id`,
            `t_d`.`attribute_id`,
            `t_d`.`value`                                  AS `default_value`,
            `t_s`.`value`                                  AS `store_value`,
            IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value`
          FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s`
              ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1
          WHERE (t_d.entity_id IN (7497)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN
                   ( .... , '85', .... ))
                AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `entity_type_id` is set properly to `4` in `catalog_product_entity_int`. While is this not needed while loading the product normally, in this specific case it seems to matter.

Comment: I'd was not everyone will need this hard-coded to `4`.  Entity type IDs will vary depending on how you built up a store.  Checkout the `eav_entity_type` table.